# JQuery (JS) in coffee script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm having problem with converting a HTML/CSS/JS page and using it on Ruby on Rails. I have the following JS code:

Java Script:

```js
function getRandomSize(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var allImages = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var width = getRandomSize(200, 400);
  var height =  getRandomSize(200, 400);
  allImages += '<img src="https://placekitten.com/'+width+'/'+height+'" alt="pretty kitty">';
}

$('#photos').append(allImages);
```

and converted it to Coffee script.

Coffee:

```js
allImages = ''

getRandomSize = (min, max) ->
  Math.round Math.random() * (max - min) + min

i = 0
while i < 25
  width = getRandomSize(200, 400)
  height = getRandomSize(200, 400)
  allImages += '<img src="https://placekitten.com/' + width + '/' + height + '" alt="pretty kitty">'
  i++
$('#photos').append allImages
```

However, it does not show images when I call them in HTML. I tested it with console log, it's working.

I'm using it on Ruby on Rails:

HTML:

```html
<section id="photos">heyyyyyyyyyyyyy</section>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

CSS:

```css
// Place all the styles related to the mood controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/



#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;

   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: "jquery in coffee script not working" "it does not show images when I call them" (what do you mean by calling them?) "i tested it, its working", be more specific, what have you tested? what is working? what is not working? how it's not working? do you have any error on the browser's console? is the method being called? "works" and "does not work" are to vague

Comment: are you wrapping your code in a document ready event?